# WinDbg failed with error 0x80004005 when debugging target machine (VM) using net

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, driver, windbg

When debugging a driver from WinDbg, I get the following error:

> Could not start debug session, error 8004005: Unspecified error

Host and target are both Windows 10 VMs on VMWare Workstation.

Comment: Did you ever find the root cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

The WDK Visual Studio addon is not loaded properly.
Currently, it could be caused due to service loading failure, as stated on WDK [download page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk):

[image]